# Which network library should be used for google cloud endpoint

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-asynctask, google-cloud-endpoints, android-networking

I am building an android application with back-end on Google App Engine. I want to use google cloud endpoint for rest APIs. Is it possible to use any other network library on client side other than Google HTTP Client API? If yes, what network library should I use to make my network calls light and fast? Other possible network libraries are Retrofit, Volley, OkHttp.

Answer (score 1):

The main answer is 'yes'.  Using Google's http client for cloud endpoints does not restrict your other networking in any way.   You could even, for example, use one of those other libraries in the same Android app, and to communicate with the same server app (through a different servlet in the same app).

Regarding the choice between Retrofit, Volley, OkHttp, etc., questions like that are not considered suitable for stackoverflow because it is really a matter of preference, and pros and cons.  SO is for questions that have a right answer.